# GET api cannot get its arguments

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have simple aspnet core api controller, when a get action, but this action cannot get its arguments from query path. Is there anything I'm using the webapi routing wrong?

action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public string Test(string arg) // arg is always null no matter what path I use
    {
        return arg;
    }
```

routes:

```
routes.MapAreaRoute(
                name: "ad",
                areaName: "Ad",
                template: "api/{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Ad" }
            );
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

logs:

> >
>       info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/api/Ad/Ad/Test/asdfasdf
>   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[9]
>         AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
>   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteConstraintMatcher[1]
>         Route value 'Ad' with key 'area' did not match the constraint 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Constraints.CompositeRouteConstraint'.
>   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteConstraintMatcher[1]
>         Route value 'Ad' with key 'area' did not match the constraint 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Constraints.CompositeRouteConstraint'.
>   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase[1]
>         Request successfully matched the route with name 'ad' and template 'api/{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id}'.
>   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
>         Executing action Api.Areas.Ad.Controllers.AdController.Test (Api)
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
>         Executing action method Api.Areas.Ad.Controllers.AdController.Test (Api) with arguments () - ModelState is Valid
>   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>         Executed action method Api.Areas.Ad.Controllers.AdController.Test (Api), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.
>   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor[4]
>         No information found on request to perform content negotiation.
>   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor[2]
>         Selected output formatter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.HttpNoContentOutputFormatter' and content type '' to write the response.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
>         Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>         Executed action Api.Areas.Ad.Controllers.AdController.Test (Api) in 193.6691ms
>   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[9]
>         Connection id "0HL9N6GCMPEP7" completed keep alive response.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 218.2123ms 204

Comment: `"api/{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`is `area:exists` suposed to be `ad`. Seems like you sent your request to `api/Ad/Ad/Test/asdfasdf`

Comment: I tried using `ad`, same issue, argument is null. Also i read that route matching is case insensitive so it should not be the problem.

Comment: try renaming arg to id. But taking it from your response your path is correct and you do get into the API controller method for sure?

Comment: Yeah, if I set a breakpoint inside the function, it is hit just arg is null.

Comment: Does it work if you change to [HttpGet("{arg}")]?

Comment: If your current Uri get's you in the method. then my answer should work. Except maybe for changing `\{ID}` to `\{args}` not entirelly sure about that one

Comment: @JuriPyykkö change to HttpGet("{arg}") does not work, log says `No actions matched the current request. Route values: area=Ad, controller=Ad, action=Test, id=asdfasdf` and fails with a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URI as shown in the exception(`http://localhost/api/Ad/Ad/Test/asdfasdf`) allows you to enter the method. One of these 2 solutions should work:

1:
Remove `/{id}` from the route and change your request Uri too:
`http://localhost/api/Ad/Ad/Test?args=asdfasdf`

2:
Either rename `/{id}` in the route too `/{args}`
or rename the parameter of your method to ID.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the parameters are taken as positional arguments, no matter what name the argument uses...

Comment: From my experience not so much. you either have to add a lot of route templates, use `[Route("{param1}/{pram2}")]` on method level. Or entirelly remove `{/ID}` and just use `?param1=value&param2=value2` at the end of your URI